# Catch msiexec command failure inside Process.Start

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I want to install an MSI using process.start and below is the code I added.

```
try {
  Process p = Process.Start("msiexec.exe", "/a D:\test.msi");
  //msiexec.exe /a "D:\test.msi"
} catch(Exception Ex) {
  //handle exception
}
```

I expected it to go to catch block if the msiexec command inside fails.

But looks like command execution status doesn't matter for Process.start.

How can I know if the command inside is successful or not?

Comment: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/740092  maybe you must read from msiexec and after that you must handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In Windows) it is customs a successful exe return 0. Any other value signals an error.
You find the valiue in [ExitProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode?view=net-6.0)
If you want to find out what failed you might have to [send the output to a console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40920740/521554).